# AngularJS input[number] truncates large numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write back to an input field of type Number

```
 <input type="number" id="viewer" value="{{ccNumber}}" />
```

When binding to the model my number.. which is 19 digits gets truncated and rounded by angular. This isn't acceptable, type must be number to work with mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/1fgfmk0h/4/

The link above is the scenario. Basically I put a 19 digit number in but when it comes back the number is rounded off. If anyone knows how to fix this issue I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The largest number available in javascript is 9007199254740992, so that's not very suprising.

Comment: You can represent your number as a string if it's just a series of digits on which you aren't performing mathematical operations. I see that mistake often, for instance, it's not because a phone number has digits that it should be numeric.

Comment: Input has to be type number in order to show the numpad on mobile devices. I can't use string, been down that road already, it shows the entire keyboard on mobile devices

Comment: @Proximo What about using `type="tel"`? Does that work?

Comment: Plalx please put that as the answer